# Generate a report containing only R scripts but no outputs

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am looking for a way to output R scripts in PDF format.

If using the option "compile report" in Rstudio, it generates a report including the output. However, the computing time of the code is quite long. Is there a way to turn it off, I guess an option like `echo = FALSE`  should be configured somewhere.

Comment: Did you try `eval=FALSE` ?

Comment: @snoram If I call rmarkdown:render from cmd, eval = FALSE is unused argument.

Comment: Another option would be to cache chunks. It saves chunk results into a binary file and loads it when you "knit" your document the next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comments by *snoram*, you can set `eval=FALSE` to prevent any code running. If you want these settings to apply to the whole document, you can specify them in the first chunk using `knitr::opts_chunk$set`. An example below:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(eval = FALSE)
```


```{r}
# your code
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, colour = Species)) +
  geom_point()
```
````

[image]

> A full explanation of knitr chunk options is available here: https://yihui.name/knitr/options/

---

**Option 2: Skip running knitr**

R Markdown runs the document through `knitr` which runs any code chunks and saves the outputs of the document. If you only wish to have the code output, we can skip the processing of this, and just pass the raw `.Rmd` file to `pandoc` (the software responsible for building the final outputted document. If we assume the file is called `test.Rmd`

```
rmarkdown::pandoc_convert("test.Rmd", to = "latex", output = "test.pdf")
```

[image]

Comment: Option 2 can be executed either in cmd or a regular R script, is that correct? That is exactly what I am looking for. Thanks.